# Need a Property to hold the result from a data table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a property tha will hold to ints  for example

int age and int numbers so.. something like  This data is comming from a function in another class that returns a DataSet, in the data set there will be those two items like:

```
Age   number
24      1
29      6
32      2
27      1
19      3
```

So like I said, at the end I would like to have  a property that contains this data and can reference at any time from different classes

so I am not sure what to use to hold that data, but it would be something like

```
public <int, int> personData
{
   get
    {
       return _personData;
    }
   set
   {
         _personData = value;
   }
}
```

so I do not know what to use for  _personData and for . And how can I access the values of such solution

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Why not just set the DataTable as a property?  That's perfectly valid.

Comment: That would violate encapsulation and expose your data storage/retrieval paterns in the API

Comment: Does order matter? You're output prints it with 24, then 29, then 32.  Do you care if the storage loses that order?

Comment: You have 2 good suggestions, either make a PersonData class with 2 properties or create an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. I'd pick one of those depending on what you're looking to do (pass an object back or pass a value back based on a key). Also, if you don't need PersonData to be a class but you just want to have a quick pair of values you can use `Tuple<T1, T2>`. Pick one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a `Dictionary<int, int>` will do it for you.

```
Dictionary<int, int> _personalData = new Dictionary<int, int>{ {24, 1}, {29, 6}, ..};
```

and to access values, you can do

```
int result = _personalData[24]; // should return 1
```

Comment: @bryanmac I believe Dictionary class keeps the order in which items are added.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PersonData
{
   public int Age{get;set;}
   public int Number {get;set;}
}
```

You can then create `List<PersonData>`

And you can access each property like so:

```
PersonData personData = new PersonData();
personData.Age=12;
personData.Number=10;
```

You can create a list of PersonData and add items doing this:

```
List<PersonData> listPersondata = new List<PersonData>();
listPersondata.Add(new PersonData(){Age=12,Number=13});
```

You can bind this List to any control like a gridview, listbox, etc.